# If $\zeta$ is a counting measure, then $\zeta^{\otimes2}(B_1\times B_2)=\sum_{x_1\ne x_2}\zeta(\{x_1\})\zeta(\{x_2\})1_{B_1\times B_2}(x_1,x_2)$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space with $\{x\}\in\mathcal E$ for all $x\in E$ and $\zeta$ be a measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Remember that $x\in E$ is called *atom* of $\zeta$ if $\zeta\{x\}\ne0$. Let $$D_\zeta:=\{x\in E:x\text{ is an atom of }\zeta\}.$$ $\zeta$ is called *purely atomic* if $D_\zeta$ is countable and $\zeta(D_\zeta^c)=0$.

Assume $\zeta$ is purely atomic. Then, $$\zeta(B)=\sum_{x\in D_\zeta}\zeta(\{x\})1_B(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E\tag1$$ for all $B\in\mathcal E$. Now, let $n\in\mathbb N$. We should have $$\zeta^{\otimes n}\left(B_1\times\cdots B_n\right)=\sum_{x\in D_\zeta^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\zeta(\{x_i\})1_{B_i}(x)\tag2$$ for all $B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal E$. However, from [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campbell%27s_theorem_(probability)](Campbell's theorem), we should have (for $n=2$) $$\zeta^{\otimes2}(B_1\times B_2)=\sum_{\substack{x_1,\:x_2\:\in D_\zeta\\x_1\ne x_2}}\zeta(\{x_1\})\zeta(\{x_2\})1_{B_1\times B_2}(x_1,x_2)\tag3$$ instead. What am I missing?

Comment: When $E$ is  singleton it appears that LHS of (3) is $1$ and RHS is $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm You are right. The claim can be found [here](https://sampling.mpi-inf.mpg.de/publications/2018-oztireli-sampling/2018-oztireli-sampling.pdf) in eq. (2.2) on p. 21. Is there anything different in the described scenario?